# Is this negation of the Parallel postulate wrong?

Tags: geometry, logic, euclidean-geometry, quantifiers

In my lecture notes it's written that the negation of

> For all lines $l$ and for all points $P$ not on $l$, there exists a unique line $m$ passing though $P$ and parallel to $l$

is

> **For all** lines $l$ and for all points $P$ not on $l$, there exists **no** line $m$ passing though $P$ and parallel to $l$

or

> **For all** lines $l$ and for all points $P$ not on $l$, there exists more than one line $m$ passing though $P$ and parallel to $l$

but I really think it's wrong to deny it this way, instead of ''For all lines $l$ and for all points $P$'',  it should be ''There exist at least a line $l$ and a point $P$...''.

Am I wrong ?

Comment: You are correct. If a proposition claims to be true for all lines and points not on the line then to prove it false you show there is at least one line and one point not on that line where the proposition is false.

Comment: I believe you want to say 'negation' where you use 'denial'; you're right that the _logical_ negation of the parallel postulate is closer to what you've said. But from a geometric sense, there are good reasons for pursuing the statements in the form they're usually given. For instance, one usually thinks of geometries as _transitive_; given any two lines, there's a transform that takes one fo the other. So a statement that's true for one line should be true for all lines.

Comment: That doesn't preclude saying something like 'for all lines $\ell$ there exists a point $P$ such that etc.', which is still weaker than the two forms you've given (that use a universal quantifier over points). But that's somewhat the point, too: by proving that there are geometries that we can make even stronger statements about than 'just' non-Euclideanness, we essentially show even stronger violations of the parallel postulate.

Comment: that's really on point thanks @Steven Stadnicki , my course is concerned with non-euclidean geometries indeed, but the problem is that I think this was intended to be a logical negation because it's inside the section about an overview on logic. But surely the confusion comes from what you wrote.

Comment: None of the three statements is a *logical negation* of the other (you're right about that), but each one of them *denies* the others in the sense that it makes them false.